# How to keep keyboard mapping after reboot?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, xmodmap, setxkbmap

In order to remap my keyboard I use the following commands:

```
$ setxkbmap -layout fr -variant latin9 -option ''
$ setxkbmap -option ctrl:nocaps
$ printf "keycode  127 = Caps_Lock NoSymbol Caps_Lock" > ~/.Xmodmap
$ xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
```

After that, everything works as expected. However, when I reboot (I noticed the same behavior on two of my computers, one is on Lubuntu 20.04 and the other on Ubuntu 20.04), I have swapcaps instead of nocaps and keycode 127 has its original mapping.

How can I prevent reboot from changing my remapping?

Comment: Well, first I'd like to know if this is normal. And then understand why is like this.